# Git: How to list specific trailers (footers) in git-log format?

Tags: git, git-log

Given the following example git commit message:

```
My commit message summary

Some more body in this message...

Signed-off-by: My name <my.name@example.com>
Issue: MYPROJ-123
```

I can now parse these '[trailers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers)' (key/value parameters in the footer) with recent Git versions (2.14+) using `git interpret-trailers --parse`.
This appears integrated into git-log formatting options as well, e.g.:

```
git log --format="%h %s %(trailers)"
```

However, it shows me all trailers, including the line breaks.

Would it be possible to limit this to the value(s) of a single trailer token? Ideally, what I'd like to accomplish is something like this as a git-log line, showing the value of the `Issue` token only:

```
0123abcd My commit message summary MYPROJ-123
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible using [trailers options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emtrailersoptionsem). Following your example the command line would be:

```
git log --format="%h %s %(trailers:key=Issue,valueonly)"
```

Comment: Thanks! My git version 2.28.0 tends to include a superfluous newline as part of the trailer value, however. Fixed with `git log --format="%h %s %(trailers:key=Issue,valueonly,separator=%x2C )"`

Comment: Git version 2.34.1 also puts in an unwanted newline